# word() function returns the different results depending on gnuplot version 5.06 and 5.22

Tags: function, gnuplot, version

I recently updated gnuplot latest version, 5.22 and my code didn't work properly. I debugged and found the reasons.

```
str="1 2"
print word(str,3)+0
```

In the previous version, 5.06 or older, the `print` shows 0 values without error.
But the latest version got error, "Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected"

Without `+0`, both results are the same, blank (no output), but the latest version treats it as string I think.

My code has lots of routine related to `word()`, so how do I resolve this problem in the new version?

Comment: Use `words` for index checks

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to make two potentially dangerous assumptions:

1. that requesting the third element from a list of two elements returns an empty string, rather than causing an error, and
2. that converting that empty string to a number will yield 0.

Assumption 1 seems to still hold in gnuplot 5.2.2, but assumption 2 does not. If you really wanted that then you could create a wrapper

```
f(x) = (x eq "" ? 0 : x)
```

and use `f(word(str,3))` instead of `word(str,3)`. However, there might be a better way to deal with non-existing elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `words` to check the index:

```
w2num(list, i) = (i > 0 && i <= words(list)) ? word(list, i)+0 : 0
```

Example:

```
w2num(list, i) = (i > 0 && i <= words(list)) ? word(list, i)+0 : 0
l = "10 20"
do for [i=-1:3] { print w2num(l, i) }
```

prints

```
0
0
10
20
0
```